# c# find the closest two numbers in a list with two columns to two number arguments

Tags: c#

I am working with Geographical Lat/Lon values and given a specific Lat/Lon combination, I need to find the closest Lat/Lon from a list of Lat/Lon locations based on US Zip Codes. Once located, I need to return the Zip Code for that location.

Sample Arguments to Find the Closest Lat/Lon

X: -76.696136 
Y: 40.095702

The DataTable Column includes Latitude, Longitude, ZipCode

I've tried the below, but the distance between the two numbers returned is greater than expected, e.g. the ZipCode returned is a considerable distance from the original Lat/Lon argument. I am not confident the OrderBy, ThenBy is actually providing the closest combination of numbers. Is there another approach available that would provide a closer match?

```
var zipMatches = zipCodeList
 .OrderBy(item => Math.Abs(Convert.ToDouble(item.Latitude) - Convert.ToDouble(searchedItem.GeoLat)))
 .ThenBy(item => Math.Abs(Convert.ToDouble(item.Longitude) - Convert.ToDouble(searchedItem.GeoLon)))
 .FirstOrDefault();
```

The expected result would be a Lat/Lon pair closest to the arguments provided.

X: -76.696136 
Y: 40.095702

Comment: I think you could do this by calculating the [Haversine distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) between each one and choosing the smallest - see e.g. https://gist.github.com/stuartd/96f78589e0b7ff293ae72bfc883b22e8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a sphere distance calculation can become quite complex. If the points to compare are not too distant from each other and you are not near the date line where the degrees jump from -180 to +180 degrees, you could make the simplifying assumption that you are on a [Euclidean plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_space) and calculate the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) using the [Pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem)

```
distance = sqrt((x1 - x0)^2 + (y1 - y0)^2)
```

Since you are not interested in the absolute magnitude but only on the relative distances, you can omit the square root calculation

```
sqrDistance = (x1 - x0)^2 + (y1 - y0)^2
```

Like this

```
double searchLat = Convert.ToDouble(searchedItem.GeoLat);
double searchLon = Convert.ToDouble(searchedItem.GeoLon);
var zipMatches = zipCodeList
     .OrderBy(item => Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble(item.Latitude) - searchLat, 2) +
                      Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble(item.Longitude) - searchLon, 2))
     .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: it might be better to leave the square root anyway for readability.

Answer (score 0):

Enhancing Olivier's answer.
First of all if location is based on Zip codes then there might be multiple same distance points and getting random first one might not be very practical.
Below code will return all points which happened to be the closest to the search point:

```
private double GetSqrDistanceBetweenPoints(GeoCoordinate point1, GeoCoordinate point2)
{
    return Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble(point1.Latitude) - point2.Latitude, 2) +
           Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble(point1.Longitude) - point2.Longitude, 2);
}
private List<GeoCoordinate> Test(List<GeoCoordinate> zipCodeList, GeoCoordinate searchedItem)
{
    var zipMatches = zipCodeList
        .ToLookup(x => GetSqrDistanceBetweenPoints(x, searchedItem))
        .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
        .FirstOrDefault()?
        .ToList();

    return zipMatches;
}
```